# I was recently contacted by blockchain, saying I have money in wallet,account is frozen ,and can recover money. Is this legit? Can't remember wallet

Tags: blockchain, wallet, wallet-recovery

I was recently contacted by blockchain Acces UK claiming that I had created a bitcoin wallet years ago. Was informed wallet has 4.2 BTC coins in it  which is equivalent to almost $40,000. The account is now dormant and frozen because there has been no activity. Was told it can be recovered by this company,and money sent to my bank account. I cannot remember any of my bitcoin information. I created the wallet and just completely forgot about it. Is this company legit, and How can I recover my lost wallet.looking forward to feedback.

Comment: It's a scam. Don't bother answering, and definitely don't send them any money.

Answer (score 1):

> **I was recently contacted by blockchain Acces UK**

Whever contacted you is almost certainly lying to you about the company name - they probably have no connection with that company.

> **Is this company legit**

### Companies House

All limited companies in the UK are registered with "Companies House":

https://find-and-update.company-information.service.gov.uk/company/11337627

> Accounts overdue
>
> Next accounts made up to 31 December 2020, due by 30 September 2021

Not a good sign in my opinion, however they are a registered company. Remember, it is very very easy to create a limited company and many criminals do so. This one is genuine but other registered limited companies may not be. You should carefully examine their filing history to get a better idea.

### Financial Conduct Authority

Companies that provide financial services are usually regulated by the UK Financial Conduct Authority (FCA)

The FCA warns consumers about criminals pretending to be Blockchain Access UK Ltd:

https://www.fca.org.uk/news/warnings/blockchain-refund-department-clone-fca-registered-emd-agent

> Almost all firms and individuals carrying out financial services activities in the UK have to be authorised or registered by us. This firm is not authorised or registered by us but has been targeting people in the UK, claiming to be an authorised firm.
>
> This is what we call a 'clone firm'; and fraudsters usually use this
> tactic when contacting people out of the blue, so you should be
> especially wary if you have been cold called. **They may use the name of
> the genuine firm**
>
> [...]
>
> FCA authorised firm details
>
> This FCA authorised firm that fraudsters are claiming to work for has
> no association with the ‘clone firm’. It is authorised to offer,
> promote or sell services or products in the UK and its correct details
> are:
>
> Firm Name: Blockchain Access UK Ltd

(my emphasis)

If you have any doubts, it would be better for you to contact the genuine business using contact details you get from official sources - do not use phone numbers, email addresses or postal addresses given to you by the people who contacted you.